# How to change the value of div id based on next/last value in array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

Now I understand very little about jquery I've only really scratched the surface, so bear with me as I try to explain. If i have and array like such:

```
var list = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

And I have a div with id "two" and some buttons:

```
<button id="buttonOne"></button>
<div id="two"></div>
<button id="buttonTwo"></button>
```

How do I change the div id to "one" if I click buttonOne or three if I click ButtonTwo?

I would post what I have tried but I've had no success. Thank you for any help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you though about setting the ID directly `element.id = "two"`? What about using `setAttribute`?

Comment: Why do you want to change the id? That is not a common thing to do and this could be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to change `id` using jquery, you can use:

```
$("#two" ).attr("id","newId");
```

However, as you can see - you will have a problem, since you are modifying your selector.
Changing ids is not a good practice (`id` is the identifier of your element).
You can use css class instead:

```
$("#yourelement" ).addClass("one");
$("#yourelement" ).removeClass("two");
```